# javascript not working but IE shows no errors

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I was testing my script in IE 8 however its not working and i.e. it isn't showing any errors. My script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var type = "hat";
    $('select#itemtype').change(function() {
        if($("select#itemtype option:selected").text(); == type) {
            $('#graphic').show();
        } else {
            $('#graphic').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: dont prepend an id selctor with tag name it infact has a negative impact on performance as jquery wont fall back to the native getElementById method

Comment: also do a strict comparison i.e use `===`

Comment: @user1461370 - You didn't even try to debug it yourself before asking here...

Comment: @Derek people have stopped doing that now, why waste the mental energy when someone else does it for free..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've added a semicolon after the text function which shouldn't be there and you're not closing the `.ready()` function properly. Here is the fixed JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var type = "hat";
    $('#itemtype').change(function() {
        if($("#itemtype option:selected").text() === type) {
            $('#graphic').show();
        } else {
            $('#graphic').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**Update:** Added Baz1nga's strict comparison suggestion.